# Is this a Dart Constructor?

Tags: dart, constructor, pipeline, codemagic

I'm still getting used to Dart and I've searched for an answer to this, but I haven't found one. What does the second line, 'ClassA._();', of the class definition do? The list declaration is only shown to give the class a reason for being.

```
class ClassA {   
   ClassA._();   
   static final List<String> someList = ["A", "B", "C"]; 
}
```

If it's a constructor, how would it be invoked?
After doing some more sleuthing I see it creates a singleton. But when is the singleton created? Is there a way to get in front of the instantiation and make some mods?

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
ClassA._();
```

Is a named constructor with the name `_`. In dart, [identifiers that start with underscore (_) are only visible inside the library it is contained in](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility).

The reason you would define a class this way, is that you want to prevent people from creating instances of this class.

Comment: mmcdon20, thank you for your response. That makes sense. The syntax is so terse.

Comment: Dart doesn't have keywords like `private` or `protected` and instead uses leading underscores in identifiers to control visibility. It is a bit unusual compared to other languages, so its something to keep in mind when reading dart code.